# PHP string comparison using '=='

Tags: php, comparison

I did a few tests with strings using '=='. I know to compare strings using '==' is not the way, but there is a weird behavior I want to solve.

I'm following the PHP documentation on page *[Comparison Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)*. This is the test I did:

```
<?php
   var_dump( "100" == "1e2" ); // Outputs boolean true
   var_dump( (int) "100" ); // int 100
   var_dump( (int) "1e2" ); // int 1
?>
```

The documentation says when we compare strings with numbers, PHP first converts the string to numbers, but when I convert '100' and '1e2' to numbers they are not equal. The comparison should outputs boolean false.

Why is this weird behavior?

Comment: Incidentally this is why it's usually best to use `===` instead of `==`, since the result is far more predictable!

Comment: Re *"compare strings using '==' is not the way"*: What *is* the way? Using three (`===`)? What is the canonical Stack Overflow question for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not all numbers are integers. `1e2` is a float (that happens to be representable as an integer, but is not *directly* convertible to an integer). Try converting to `float`s rather than `int`s:

```php
<?php 
   var_dump( "100" == "1e2" ); // bool(true)
   var_dump( (float) "100" );  // float(100)
   var_dump( (float) "1e2" );  // float(100)
?>
```

Comment: To expand on this, here is the explanation in the docs. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion   "If the string does not contain any of the characters '.', 'e', or 'E' and the numeric value fits into integer type limits (as defined by PHP_INT_MAX), the string will be evaluated as an integer. In all other cases it will be evaluated as a float."

Answer (score 1):

[Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) is not equal to [Type Casting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php#language.types.typecasting)

From the Type Juggling page

> If either operand is a float, then both operands are evaluated as floats, and the result will be a float. Otherwise, the operands will be interpreted as integers, and the result will also be an integer.